# Convert Swift Array of Realm Objects Back to Realm Results

Tags: swift3, realm

I have an `Entry` class that has a list of `FieldValue` objects within it:

```
class Entry: Object{
  let fieldValues = List<FieldValue>()
  //...
}

class FieldValue: Object{
  dynamic var total = 0
  //...
}
```

I do a bunch of filtering on some entries in a query like this:

```
var entryObjects = realm.objects(Entry.self).filter(...)
```

I now want to `sum` the `total` values for all the `fieldValues` still present in my filtered `entryObjects`. So if I iterate through all my entries, I can build an array of `FieldValue` objects like this:

```
var fieldValues = [FieldValue]()
for entry in entryObjects{
  fieldValues += entry.fieldValues  
}
```

I now have `fieldValues` of type `[FieldValue]`. But in order to do a `sum` on its `total` property, it has to be of type `Results<FieldValue>`:

```
let total:Int = fieldValues.sum(ofProperty: "total") <-- /// Error! ///
```

How do I convert my `[FieldValue]` array back to `Results<FieldValue>` so I can do aggregate operations on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
let entryObjects = realm.objects(Entry.self).filter(...)
let total = entryObjects.map({ $0.fieldValues.sum(ofProperty: "total") }).reduce(0, +)
```

When Realm support aggregate operations on nested keypaths ([#3392](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3392)) it'll be possible to use KVC for this, but that's still in progress.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I ended up using `reduce` in a similar fashion, but this is even less code than what I came up with.